# VMware Player and disabling the Screen Saver

Tags: screensaver, vmware-player, vmware-workstation

When I am using a guest OS in VMware, 16.04 is not seeing the keystrokes or mouse movements so the Screen Saver times out and my world goes black. Fortunately 16.04 is smart enough to grab the next lot of keystrokes for the password and let me back to what I was doing.

Is there some way to automatate (Bash?) that disables the Screen Saver, starts VMWare and re-enable the Screen Saver when I quit VM?